# Visual Studio Publishing Wizard lacks (Azure) App Service Target in available targets list

Tags: visual-studio, azure, deployment

As of [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-dotnet#launch-the-publish-wizard) and this picture in particular:
[image]

the list has the "App Service" option.

In my Visual Studio it apparently hasn't.
I am sure that must be some sort of extension or some additional feature added to my Visual Studio, but I can't understand which one.

The official page reg. **Prerequisites** mentions:

> To complete this tutorial, install Visual Studio 2017 with the ASP.NET and web development workload.
>
> If you've installed Visual Studio 2017 already:
>
> Install the latest updates in Visual Studio by clicking Help > Check
>   for Updates. Add the workload by clicking Tools > Get Tools and
>   Features.

But that's just a common words, nothing in particular: neither Visual Studio particular version or something like that.
My Visual Studio mostly always updated to the last versions, but I never seen such option available.

... and yes, I am an ASP.NET developer for many years (and my VS definitely always has "ASP.NET and web development workload" including latest ASP.NET Core ones), but that looks so dumb that I can't find the way of having the "App Service" in my publishing tools.

[image: My VS Setup tree]

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Run the Visual Studio installer from the **Tools/Get Tools and Features** menu and check that you have the Azure development workload installed.

Comment: Yeah, this is the way how I open the Setup, but the thing is I don't see such type of components anywhere in the list -- neither in workloads details nor individual components list. There are "Azure development" and "Asp.net and web development" workloads I see (and they already checked), but on the right (the child elements of the workloads) don't have any mentioning of Azure-like deployment stuff. (One of the example on my second picture attached above).